# What happens at the background when variables are declared in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables

I would like to know what happens behind the scene when variables are declared in ruby. For example, What differentiates these variables from one another?

```
#normal variables
name = "John"

#instant variables
@name = "John"

#class variables
@@name = "John"

#class instance variables
def self.namer
   @name = "John"
end

#constants
NAME = "John"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal variables, like `name`, are local. They're only available in the scope in which they were declared.

```
class Dog
  def set_a_variable
    name = "Fido"
  end
  def show_a_variable
    name
  end
end

my_dog = Dog.new
my_dog.set_a_variable
my_dog.show_a_variable
=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `name'
```

Instance variables, like `@name`, belong to the instance of a class, so every instance method for an instance of a class has access to that variable. If not set, `nil` is assumed.

```
class Dog
  def set_a_variable
    @name = "Fido"
  end
  def show_a_variable
    @name
  end
end

my_dog = Dog.new
my_dog.set_a_variable
my_dog.show_a_variable
=> "Fido"
my_second_dog = Dog.new
my_second_dog.show_a_variable
=> nil # not shared between different instances
```

Class variables, like `@@legs`, are accessible by all instances of a class, so every every instance has access to that variable.  They're also inherited by sub-classes.

```
class Animal
  def set_a_variable
    @@legs = 4
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  def show_a_variable
    @@legs
  end
end

my_animal = Animal.new
my_animal.set_a_variable
my_dog = Dog.new
my_dog.show_a_variable
=> 4
my_second_dog = Dog.new
my_second_dog.show_a_variable
=> 4
```

Class instance variables (`@name` defined in a class method) belong to the specific class, so every instance method has access to that variable, but it's not inherited by child classes.

```
class Animal
  def self.set_a_variable
    @legs = 2
  end
  def self.show_a_variable
    @legs
  end
  def show_a_variable
    self.class.show_a_variable
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  def self.set_a_variable
    @legs = 4
  end
end

my_dog = Dog.new
Dog.set_a_variable
my_animal = Animal.new 
Animal.set_a_variable
my_dog.show_a_variable
=> 4
```

Constants are NOT global, but are accessible via scoping anywhere.

```
class Animal
  LEGS = 4
end

class Dog
  def show_a_variable
    Animal::LEGS
  end
end

my_dog = Dog.new
my_dog.show_a_variable
=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are never declared in Ruby. They just spring into existence when they are first assigned.

Comment: I am sure something is responsible for their coming into existence.

Answer (score -1):

Their scope differentiates them.